# Laravel and Vue in WAMP -- components don't compile, just appear as their component names

Tags: laravel, vue.js, wamp

I installed laravel in WAMP using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mysite --prefer-dist
```

And I can access the splash page at localhost/mysite/public.

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-vue-components) I should be able to add examplecomponent.vue to this view or any other by using:

```
<example-component></example-component>
```

But when I do this, I see nothing on the page and the above template tag in the HTML source. But not the actual component.

I have run

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm run dev
```

But this didn't solve the problem.

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Did you check the developer console/

Comment: component should be in laravel default layout or between ```<div id="app"></div>```

Comment: @Devon the console is blank

Comment: Mohammad b - I tried putting it inside div#app, no use

Comment: Did you modify the webpack.mix.js file? If not, it may be useful to pull up the js on the browser and find the 'example-component' value.

Comment: Dimitri - I didn't modify webpack.mix.js. Hmm there appears to be no JS... but app.js is there in the js folder. edit: app.js is there in the public folders, but I can't see that it's being loaded anywhere

Answer (score 0):

**Package.json**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
  }
}
```

and the modify your webpack.mix.js

Compare your package.json to this.

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

Comment: What do I do with webpack.mix.js? It failed to compile with that package.json - '--progress' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn --progress ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\wamp64\www\mysite\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\wamp64\www\mysite\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit